# Capacitance measurement, mpr121 touch sensing keyboard

Tags: sensor, touch-panel

I have been assigned a project where I have to use interface an [MPR121](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/MPR121.pdf) capacitive touch sensing controller with a microcontroller. Aside from the touch detection, one of the requests for the project was capacitance measurement from the touch pins, and to display it's change using graphs.

[image]
*[image credit](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/9695)*

I know that I can get the capacity of the electrode from 2<sup>nd</sup> filtered data registers that contains 10 bits of data, 2 msb and 8 lsb.

My question is do all these 10 bits represent the capacity, or are they used for some other info rather then only capacity? Thank you.

Comment: What does the datasheet say?

Comment: Datasheet says "The 2nd level filter result is 10bit and stored in the output data registers 0x04~0x1D as the immediate capacitance of each sensing input".